# Загрузка данных ajax при открытии страницы

Tags: ajax

Здравствуйте, как реализовать следующие, открывается страница и некий блок автоматом загружается ajax'om или js кодом. Это может быть блок или меню, но нужно, чтобы грузилось автоматом ajax'ом. Подскажите, куда копать?

Comment: Так копать или готовое решение? :)

Answer (score 3):

jQuery $(document).ready [См. тут](http://jquery-docs.ru/events/ready/)

Answer (score 2):

Откровенно говоря абсолютно не понятно в чем проблема? Пример с использованием prototype(хотя повторюсь - в чем тут проблема не панатна...)

На сервере, что-то типа:

```
<?
// db connection
$dbRes = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY addData DESC LIMIT 5');
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbRes)){
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);

// допустим в результате выборки мы получили данные типа
$lastComments = array(
array('author' => 'Author1','addTime' => '00:00','content' => 'Some text ....'),
array('author' => 'Author2','addTime' => '00:00','content' => 'Some text ....'),
array('author' => 'Author3','addTime' => '00:00','content' => 'Some text ....'),
array('author' => 'Author4','addTime' => '00:00','content' => 'Some text ....'),
array('author' => 'Author5','addTime' => '00:00','content' => 'Some text ....')
);
// и выводим
echo json_encode($lastComments);
```

На клиенте:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
    <script>
    function createCommentsHtml(comments) {
      comments.each(function(comment){
        var commentWrapper = new Element("div",{"class":"comment"});
        var authorEl = new Element("div",{"class":"author"}).update(comment.author);
        var contentEl = new Element("div",{"class":"content"}).update(comment.content);
        var addTimeEl = new Element("span",{"class":"addTime"}).update(comment.addTime);
        commentWrapper.appendChild(authorEl);
        commentWrapper.appendChild(contentEl);
        commentWrapper.appendChild(addTimeEl);
        $("lastComments").appendChild(commentWrapper);
      });
    };

    Event.observe(window, "load", function(){
        new Ajax.Request("/getLastComments.php",{
            onSuccess: function(request){
                createCommentsHtml(request.responseText.evalJSON(true))
            }
        })
    });

    Event.observe(window,"load", function(){
        //  тут остальной код...
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="lastComments"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Как вариант - можно полностью генерировать html не дожидаясь загрузки, а на `window.onload` просто добавлять его на страницу

---

Поправил клиентский код, немного дополнил ответ.

---

Будем формировать html такого вида:

<div id="productWrapper">
     Товаров:
       <span id="product_name"> имя </span>
       <span id="product_total">кол-во </span> |
       <span id="basket_price"> сумма </span>
</div>

На сервер формируешь массив типа:

```
 $data = array('name' => 'Имя продукта', 'total' => '100500', 'price' => '100');
 // раз ты такой дуб - формируешь массив именно такого вида
 // т.е. не изменяй ключи, измени только их значения
 // ну и выводишь
 echo json_encode($data);
```

На клиенте теперь все намного проще т.к. товар единичный( если же товаров много - учим матчасть, а именно html(и там узнаем что если мы пишем для элемента id - значит он по определению уникален либо еденичен) ), вообщем если у тебя продуктов много - вини самого себя.

В html страничке у нас должен быть:

```
     <div id="productWrapper">
         <!--сюда мы будем вставлять сформированный html-->
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createCommentsHtml(data) {
      var productWrapper = $("productWrapper");
      var productNameEl = new Element("span",{id:"productName"}).update(data.name);
      var productTotalEl = new Element("span",{id:"productTotal"}).update("кол-во "+data.total);
      var basketPriceEl = new Element("span",{id:"basket_price"}).update(data.price + " руб.")
     productWrapper.apendChild(productNameEl);
     productWrapper.appendChild(productTotalEl);
     productWrapper.appendChild(basketPriceEl);
    };

    Event.observe(window, "load", function(){
        new Ajax.Request("/getLastComments.php",{
            onSuccess: function(request){
                createCommentsHtml(request.responseText.evalJSON(true))
            }
        })
});
```

Если я сделал не то - разбирайся, если что-то не работает - ищи ошибки, я и так уже написал через чур развернутый ответ...

Comment: Что то, как то не выводит =) 
Взял библиотеку от сюда  
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js  
добавил функцию в контроллер ajax     

    function test_ajax() {
    $data = $this->db->get('catalog')->result_array();
    echo json_encode($data);
    }  
  
в js коде изменил только адрес на /ajax/test_ajax, а зайдя на прямую в /ajax/test_ajax, выводятся все данные  
все это дело в codeigniter 2.1.0

Comment: Странно, сделал все как вы написали, изменил только путь к сервеному скрипту, и в запросе свою таблицу подставил.работать не хочет, а если захожу на прямую то как положено выводит данные из таблице, может библиотека старая https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js ? или в чем может быть дело..

Comment: Дело может быть в том что вы не переписали формирование элементов и т.д. должным образом( тут я вам помочь не смогу ), код я тестил - все работает.

Comment: А как быть? в js я дуб. мне кажется дело нужно до конца помочь..огорчаться перед новым годом не хочется :D
Просто, пример формирования элементов

Comment: Пример формирования есть в коде, если вы не понимаете что в этом коде необходимо поменять для вашего случая то вы дуб не только в JS.

Comment: Так все заработало,спасибо. единственное, как вы уже знаете что я "дуб" в js, могли бы написать за меня формирование? то есть не эти дивы с классами для Комментов, а вот просто следующий блок  
  
    
    <a href="/cart/"><img src="/img/img_cart.png" class="alpha" /></a>
 <a href="/cart/">ваша корзина</a><br />Товаров: <span id="busket_qty"> кол-во </span> | <span id="busket_price"> сумма </span> руб.